# fill datagridview column with images from image path column

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

I have Access table with fields, in which there is some data and path to the image.
I've created `DataGridViewImageColumn`, and then I have no idea, how to load some image from some path, and how to work with it.
here is the form
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/97095287.jpg/

the field with path is hidden, and you see, there is some image column

Comment: posted image of form, anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the sample code of how to put images in a cell in a DataGridViewImageColumn

```
  private void createGraphicsColumn()
    {
        Icon treeIcon = new Icon(this.GetType(), "tree.ico");
        DataGridViewImageColumn iconColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        iconColumn.Image = treeIcon.ToBitmap();
        iconColumn.Name = "Tree";
        iconColumn.HeaderText = "Nice tree";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, iconColumn);
    }
```